# loop into mutliple tables with plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to interate 2 tables, and get their records at each iteration then execute a query according to those two rows returned.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION buffer_oe() RETURNS SETOF sige.buffer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r sige.buffer%rowtype;
    r1 sige.object_elevation%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT * FROM sige.buffer poly
    LOOP
        RETURN NEXT r; 
    END LOOP;
        FOR r1 IN SELECT * FROM sige.object_elevation oe
    LOOP
        RETURN NEXT r1; 
    END LOOP;
    select true  from sige.buffer poly,sige.object_elevation oe
    where st_intersects(r.geom,r1.geom) and r.id<>r1.id;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

when I excute the function I get this error ; Bad type of record given to `Return Next`

I'm a newbie in plpgsql. I don't know what I'm missing, your help would precious.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide complete information. Postgres version? What do you want to return from the function *exactly*? (Provide example rows to clarify.) If you really want to return rows from two tables: Is the row type of `sige.buffer` and sige.object_elevation identical?

Comment: I want to have all records from `sige.buffer` where the  `id` is different than the one from `sige.object_elevation` and the two tables are intersecting. So I wanted to loop rows of the first table then compare them to the second ones and get after that those who verify the condition.